# Why doesn't this template code from the Discover Metor book work?

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze

Working my way through the Discover Meteor book. The code form chapters on creating postItem templates that include a link to specific posts just doesn't 'work' (no errors, but no result either).

See linked gists for code I'm using [1]. There are no errors in the console. I've also read up about changes introduced in Meteor 0.8 with Blaze and I suspect that this is causing the problem, however, the documentation seems to suggest template helper usage in my case is the same[2] and I can see from looking at various meteor created scripts such as router.js that older templating systems are at least attempted to be supported [3].

Why doesn't this code work? And is there a way to make only slight changes to get it working rather than moving over to iron-router and potentially departing too far from the edition of Discover Meteor that I'm using?

[1] client/views/posts/post_item.html: https://gist.github.com/Trindaz/11139437; client/helpers/router.js: https://gist.github.com/Trindaz/11139409;

[2] http://meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes#Template Helpers [Note: space before 'Helpers' in this link breaks it] This appears to be more about block helpers than the way I'm using helpers, but seems to be the extent of any discussion on helper usage so I assumed everything else remained unchanged.

[3] https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/blob/master/lib/router_client.js#L88

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer almost immediately after writing this up, leaving question up for future googlers.

The problem seems to be caused by `UI.body` member assignments at https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/blob/v0.6.1/lib/router_client.js#L89-L90. This breaks changes introduced in Meteor 0.8.0-rc3 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/oatU1zzcaeQ/54ay-pPlRrwJ.

From the release: "Templates no longer automatically access the helpers of ancestors [11]. If you were declaring helpers with UI.body.helpers you need to switch to UI.registerHelper instead."

This may all be redundant now as work has moved to iron-router.